# How to understand a simple assert statement in Python, moving a Point instance

Tags: python, unit-testing, assert

I have written the following code for a Point class, and its methods. I want to know how to apply assert statement to test if the Point x, y coordinates moved correctly. I assume that the assert statement tests the validity of the resulting coordinates after a move method is applied to the Point instance. Can you please suggest how i should write an assert statement that validates all given instances of a Point class are moved correctly?

```
class Point(object): # Modify here
    #Creates a point on the x,y coordinate system
    def __init__(self,x,y):# The __init__ constructor takes the arguments self( the current instance of the class), and positions x and y
        #Defines x and y variables
        self.x = x # Define self's x attribute.
        self.y = y
    #Moves the given point by dx and dy
    def move(self,dx,dy):#
        #Move the point to different location
        self.x=self.x+dx# the self's x + change in x
        self.y=self.y+dy
    #returns string representation of class Point
    def __str__(self,x,y):
        return "Point location:",(self.x,self.y) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Tests for point
    # ==================================
    def testPoint(x, y):
        p = Point(0, -1)  # create a point instance
        p.move(2, 2)  # Use method move, move the point object by x=2 and y=2

        assert p.x == 2
        assert p.y ==1
        print 'Success! Point tests passed!'


testPoint(0,-1)
```

Comment: I don't quite understand your question.  What constitutes "all instances of a point class are moved correctly"?  You can't effectively test *all* points except in trivial terms: a check within the move routine (the only place you're guaranteed to have 100% checking, by design), would merely check the arithmetic that you use to move the item, a structural tautology.  If you're asking about what test cases to run, you've already written the prototype with `testPoint`.  Can you elaborate a little on what you need -- perhaps two or three more examples?

Comment: What i meant is, How can an assert statement test,for example a testPoint (3,4), and a move method p.move (3,3), can be validated to give (6,7). In other words,  how can i test for any given testPoint, test if the move method moved the Point without AssertionError. If that makes sense? I'm limited in my python language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need -- a method parameterized for the given input?

```
def testPoint(x, y, move_x, move_y):
    p = Point(x, y)  # create a point instance
    p.move(move_x, move_y)  # Use method move, move the point object by x=2 and y=2

    assert p.x == x + move_x and \
           p.y == y + move_y
```

You can then execute this for a variety of starting points and movement vectors.